# Java Properties File in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

That's basically it...How do I create it?? I've been trying to find it and googling for it but found nothing yet...maybe I'm just overlooking it...but I already got sort of desperate...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Right click in the file tree, new->File.
give it the suffix .properties and it will act as a properties file.

Comment: Odd that it's not a default setting. I suspected it was too. When I didn't find it, I figured I was maybe missing out on something.